# PHP comparing a value from sql database table to a php variable taken from a form

Tags: php, sql

So this is a php file that inserts a product from a webpage to the cart at the click of the add to cart button. When the user clicks on the add to cart button it adds the product to the cart(SQL database) with the quantity that they specified(Max is 5).

**Problem:** The issue is that if they were to change the quantity, it would only work with the first product they added. Any other items will get added, but if they change the quantity and proceed to add it again, it will create a duplicate.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, but I would guess that it would have to do with how my if statement accesses my table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I will break down what each part of the code is supposed to do

```
if($result->num_rows==0){
$total=$price * $quantity;
$sql = "INSERT INTO cart (prod_id, name, price, quantity)
VALUES('$prod_id', '$name', '$total', '$quantity')";
}
```

The code above basically makes it so that if the table is empty, to simply insert the data of the chosen product

```
else{
if($row['prod_id']==$prod_id)
{

  if(($row['quantity']==5)||
    ($row['quantity']==4 && $quantity>1)||
    ($row['quantity']==3 && $quantity>2)||
    ($row['quantity']==2 && $quantity>3)||
    ($row['quantity']==1 && $quantity>4))
     {
       echo "Quantity exceeds limit";
     }
     else{
         $total=$price * $quantity;
         $sql="UPDATE cart
         SET price = price + '$total', quantity = quantity + '$quantity'
         WHERE prod_id = '$prod_id'";     
        }
}
```

Continuing from the if statement, if the table isn't empty then if the value from the row column 'prod_id' is equal to the $prod_id taken from the form, then it continues to the if statment. This one is input validation for the quantity that they input, as the max is five. It makes sure that the input is never equal to 5 and adjusts accordingly. This is because once it gets to this point, it assumes that the table is not empty, so the user must have already added an item to the cart. if it gets to the else statement then it just gets the total price depending if they got more than 1, and it updates the product in the table instead of adding a new one.

```
else{
    if($row['prod_id']==$_REQUEST['id'])
    {
        $total=$price * $quantity;
        $sql="UPDATE cart
        SET price = price + '$total', quantity = quantity + '$quantity'
        WHERE prod_id = '$prod_id'";
    }
    else{
        $total=$price * $quantity;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (prod_id, name, price, quantity)
        VALUES('$prod_id', '$name', '$total', '$quantity')";
    }

  }

}
```

This last section seems a bit wonky now that I'm looking at it, so as I said in the beginning, any help is appreciated!

Below is the entire code snippet

```
... 
$sql="SELECT * FROM cart";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row= $result->fetch_array();

$prod_id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$quantity=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
$name= $_REQUEST['amd'];
$price= $_REQUEST['price'];

if($result->num_rows==0){
    $total=$price * $quantity;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (prod_id, name, price, quantity)
    VALUES('$prod_id', '$name', '$total', '$quantity')";
}
else{
    if($row['prod_id']==$prod_id)
    {
        
      if(($row['quantity']==5)||
        ($row['quantity']==4 && $quantity>1)||
        ($row['quantity']==3 && $quantity>2)||
        ($row['quantity']==2 && $quantity>3)||
        ($row['quantity']==1 && $quantity>4))
         {
           echo "Quantity exceeds limit";
         }
         else{
             $total=$price * $quantity;
             $sql="UPDATE cart
             SET price = price + '$total', quantity = quantity + '$quantity'
             WHERE prod_id = '$prod_id'";     
            }
    }
    else{
        if($row['prod_id']==$_REQUEST['id'])
        {
            $total=$price * $quantity;
            $sql="UPDATE cart
            SET price = price + '$total', quantity = quantity + '$quantity'
            WHERE prod_id = '$prod_id'";
        }
        else{
            $total=$price * $quantity;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (prod_id, name, price, quantity)
            VALUES('$prod_id', '$name', '$total', '$quantity')";
        }
        
    }
   
}
...
```

Comment: What confuses me when i look into your code is the first line `$sql="SELECT * FROM cart";`. Are you sure that fetching all items from the cart table is a good idea in the first place ? There could be plenty items which are not even related to the current user cart. Moreover in case of multiple items in the cart you would still require some sort of loop to iterate over. First thing to do in your case, is to grab specific cart for a specific user from database. All else is secondary. And most of the `if` statements are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

So analyzing the code, you INSERT data only when `$result->num_rows` is equal to 0 and where `$row['prod_id']==$_REQUEST['id']` is FALSE.

I think that all your if clauses inside the ELSE statement of the `$result->num_rows==0`'s if clause, result FALSE because the `prod_id` index of `$row` variable is not defined.

I think you should check the values of the $row variable, with a `print_r();` or `var_dump();`, preceded by and `echo '<pre>';`

Comment: so I did print_r(); and it seems that $row variable doesn't get updated with the new product when the user selects a different product, it stays at the one they started with.

Comment: Can you show the output of the print_r() before inserting a new product and after?

Comment: It seems that I was able to figure out how to get the duplicates to stop getting through. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you update the question describing the answer to this question?

Comment: I'll update it tomorrow, I'm busy at the moment